# mysql before insert trigger Error Code 1364: Field does not have a default value and Error Code 1442. Can't update table in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a hierarchical table (left/right values to determine the hierarchy) in my database and I would like to add a "before insert" trigger.  One of the problems with large hierarchical tables of this sort is that it can be hard to figure out what has to change when you insert a new item into the hierarchy.  So I wanted to automate this in my trigger.

So, my table looks like this...

```
    name varchar(25) not null,
    leftValue int not null,
    rightValue int not null
```

Some data...

```
    'DEFAULT',           1, 10
    'FirstChild',        2, 3
    'SecondChild',       4, 7
    'SecondChildsChild', 5, 6
    'ThirdChild',        8, 9
```

Now I want to add a 'FirstChildsChild'.  This will affect every row except default.  I would like the user to only have to do something simple like this...

```
    SET parent = 3;  -- The left value of FirstChild
    insert into myTable (name, leftValue) VALUES ('FirstChildsChild', parent)
```

My new table (after properly executing the trigger that I am having trouble with) should look like this...

```
    'DEFAULT',           1, 12
    'FirstChild',        2, 5
    'FirstChildsChild',  3, 4
    'SecondChild',       6, 9
    'SecondChildsChild', 7, 8
    'ThirdChild',        10, 11
```

So I wrote the following trigger...

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `myTrigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
    begin
        SET new.rightValue = new.leftValue + 1;

        UPDATE MissionFactors SET
            leftValue = leftValue + 2
        WHERE
            leftValue >= new.leftValue;

        UPDATE MissionFactors SET
            rightValue = rightValue + 2
        WHERE 
            rightValue >= new.leftValue;
    END
```

FINALLY my questions:
1. Since the trigger is a BEFORE insert, why won't it let me leave the right value undefined in my insert statement?  The trigger fills in the value.

```
    Error Code: 1364. Field 'rightValue' doesn't have a default value.
```

1. If I do pass in a right value...

   ```
   Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'mytable' in stored function/trigger
   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
   ```

I could write a stored procedure to do all of this.  But I thought that this type of thing was one of the reasons why triggers were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.

You have to put the column nullable if you don't want it to appear in your insert's column list even if a trigger sets a default value.

For your second problem, you can't update a table while it's open for inserting. In Oracle there is a similar problem called 'mutating table'. If you want to do this you have to use several triggers including an after statement trigger that update the table.